# RichTextBox Silverlight Selected text replacement

Tags: .net, silverlight, tags, richtextbox

Ok, I have a class that uses inheritance of Richtextbox.

- INPUT:

I need to get the selected text from a RichTextBox and replace it with some tags, I mean:

```
A sample text to replace but only the selected sample word
```

And I select "sample" and click a button to transform it to:

```
A <A>sample</A> text to replace but only the selected sample word
```

The code for the replace that I been using is:

```
string selected = this.Selection.Text.Trim();

            if (selected.Length > 0)
            {
                this.Html = this.FormatedText.Replace(selected, string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", tagName, selected));
            }
```

Html and FormatedText are attributes of my class

The problem is that the RichTextBox.selection.text gets sample and if I try to use string.replace all the sample words will be marked, not only the selected one.

- NEEDS:

¿How can I get the selected word and the initial position of the selected word in the original text and then get all the text in my RichTextBox with the new insertions?

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. Show us the String.Replace code as well.

Comment: why do you want to use the replace function... replace looks for all occurances and replaces them... i think that what i wrote below works the way you want it to do

Comment: It can works, but, Then, how can I get all the text in the RichTextBox??????

Comment: there's no textrange in silverlight :(

Comment: then we have to look for another solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is select from the beginning of the content in richtextbox to the start of the selected text and then get selected text and .lenght to it :) :

```
 string selected = this.Selection.Text;

            if (selected.Length > 0)
            {
                selected = selected.Trim();

                //Change the selection from the start of the full text to the start of the selection text
                this.Selection.Select(this.ContentStart, this.Selection.Start);

                string init = this.FormatedText.Substring(0, this.Selection.Text.Length);
                string final = this.FormatedText.Substring(this.Selection.Text.Length + selected.Length, this.FormatedText.Length - (this.Selection.Text.Length + selected.Length));

                this.Html = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", init, string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", tagName, selected), final);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rtb.Selection.Text = "<A>" + rtb.Selection.Text + "</A>";
    }
```

rtb is RichTextBox

edit:

hope this is what you want... now you get all the changed items

```
        rtb.Selection.Text = "<A>" + rtb.Selection.Text + "</A>";

        //this works in silverlight
        rtb.SelectAll();
        string all = rtb.Selection.Text;

        List<string> allThatChanged = new List<string>();
        while (all.Contains("<A>"))
        {

            allThatChanged.Add(all.Substring(all.IndexOf("<A>"), all.IndexOf("</A>") - all.IndexOf("<A>") + 4));
            all = all.Remove(all.IndexOf("<A>"), all.IndexOf("</A>") - all.IndexOf("<A>") + 4);
        }
```

Comment: Then, How can I get all the text inserted in the Richtextbox with that replacements???????????

Comment: you said that you want 
`A sample text to replace but only the selected sample word` where sample is selected to replace with 
`A <A>sample</A> text to replace but only the selected sample word` and that is exactly what the code does... select a word and click a button and you will get the above

Comment: @Daniel do you want to replace all the text or not? We are really confused.

Comment: I want to replace the selected text and then... get all the text in the richtextbox with the new tags on it!!!!

Comment: Theres no TextRange class in Silverlight!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :(